# Flutter calling Riverpod function without using context.read()

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, hook-widgets

By default after defining `Riverpod` providers we can click on any widget to call some method such as getting data from webservice or another things.

for example:

```dart
context.read(washingServiceProvider.notifier).getService;
```

now my problem is how can i call this `getService` without clicking on any widget? when i try to use this code:

```dart
class GetServices extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final washing = useProvider(washingServiceProvider.notifier);
    washing.getService();

    return Scaffold();
 ...
}
```

i get this error:

```
E/flutter ( 3398): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(103)] Dart Unhandled Exception: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
E/flutter ( 3398): This UncontrolledProviderScope widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
E/flutter ( 3398): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
E/flutter ( 3398):   UncontrolledProviderScope
E/flutter ( 3398): The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
E/flutter ( 3398):   GetServices, stack trace: #0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4217:11)
E/flutter ( 3398): #1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4232:6)
E/flutter ( 3398): #2      ProviderElement._debugMarkWillChange.<anonymous closure> (package:riverpod/src/framework/base_provider.dart:660:16)
E/flutter ( 3398): #3      ProviderElement._debugMarkWillChange (package:riverpod/src/framework/base_provider.dart:664:6)
E/flutter ( 3398): #4      ProviderStateBase.exposedValue=.<anonymous closure> (package:riverpod/src/framework/base_provider.dart:900:16)
E/flutter ( 3398): #5      ProviderStateBase.exposedValue= (package:riverpod/src/framework/base_provider.dart:902:6)
E/flutter ( 3398): #6      _StateNotifierProviderState._listener (package:riverpod/src/state_notifier_provider.dart:92:5)
E/flutter ( 3398): #7      StateNotifier.state= (package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart:162:31)
E/flutter ( 3398): #8      RequestStateNotifier.makeRequest (package:washing_app/core/service/network/request_state_notifier.dart:10:7)
E/flutter ( 3398): #9      WashingRequestNotifier.getService (package:washing_app/src/screens/dashboard/tabs/category_products/repository/washing_service_repository.dart:98:7)
E/flutter ( 3398): #10     GetServices.build (package:washing_app/src/screens/dashboard/get_services.dart:39:13)
E/flutter ( 3398): #11     StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4648:28)
E/flutter ( 3398): #12     HookElement.build (package:flutter_hooks/src/framework.dart:417:27)
E/flutter ( 3398): #13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
E/flutter ( 3398): #14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
E/flutter ( 3398): #15     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4655:5)
E/flutter ( 3398): #16     HookElement.update (package:flutter_hooks/src/framework.dart:379:11)
E/flutter ( 3398): #17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
E/flutter ( 3398): #18     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4599:16)
E/flutter ( 3398): #19     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
E/flutter ( 3398): #20     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4655:5)
E/flutter ( 3398): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
E/flutter ( 3398): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6090:14)
E/flutter ( 3398): #23     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
E/flutter ( 3398): #24     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4599:16)
E/flutter ( 3398): #25     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
E/flutter ( 3398): #26     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4655:5)
E/flutter ( 3398): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
E/flutter ( 3398): #28     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6090:14)
E/flutter ( 3398): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
E/flutter ( 3398): #30     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6090:14)
E/flutter ( 3398): #31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
E/flutter ( 3398): #32     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4599:16)
E/flutter ( 3398): #33     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
E/flutter ( 3398): #34     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
E/flutter ( 3398): #35     StatefulElement.up
E/flutter ( 3398): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(103)] Dart Unhandled Exception: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

E/flutter ( 3398): This UncontrolledProviderScope widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
```

my defined provider:

```dart
final washingServicesRepositoryProvider = Provider((ref) => WashingServiceRepository(ref.read));
final washingServiceProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<WashingRequestNotifier, NetworkRequestState<WashingServicesResponseStructure>>(
        (ref) => WashingRequestNotifier(ref.watch(washingServicesRepositoryProvider)));

class WashingServiceRepository {
  final Reader _reader;

  WashingServiceRepository(this._reader);

  Future<WashingServicesResponseStructure> getService() async {
    try {
      const _r = RetryOptions(maxAttempts: 3);
      final _res = await _r.retry(() => _reader(dioProvider)
          .post(
            Server.$getData,
            options: Options(
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            ),
          )
          ..timeout(const Duration(seconds: 30)),
          retryIf: (e) => e is SocketException || e is TimeoutException);

      return WashingServicesResponseStructure.fromJson(_res.data as Map<String, dynamic>);
    } on DioError catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

}

class WashingRequestNotifier extends RequestStateNotifier<WashingServicesResponseStructure> {
  final WashingServiceRepository _washingServiceRepository;

  WashingRequestNotifier(this._washingServiceRepository);

  Future<NetworkRequestState<WashingServicesResponseStructure>> getService() =>
      makeRequest(() => _washingServiceRepository.getService());
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, here `getService` is the Future. And to change UI `HookWidget` use `useEffect`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh you right :) problem solved

Comment: how did u solve it ?

Comment: @FahmiSawalha you should use `useEffect`